# Add a column in MS SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I wanted to add a column in MS SQL Server. Will it affect any existing stored procedures or triggers or dbms jobs etc? AFAIK, in Oracle once you add a new column to an existing table, you need to recompile any invalid objects. How bout in MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a column to an existing table, in theory and best practices world is easy, but in reality it is not always as easy as ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN.

The risk is that any procedure, view or application code that uses a “Select *” or an “Insert  Values <…>” (without column names explicitly stated) may not function, or may not function correctly, with an additional column added to the table.

Also note there could be temp tables, table variables and table value parameters built off the table that an additional column affects as well.  Best practices and my database development guidelines says not to use the “Select *” or the “Insert  Values <…>”.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have a table with ID, Name, and Status columns in your table

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), Status INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1,'Name')
```

It will throw error `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.` Because in this query, inserting only first two column values and `Status is missing`. If you add Status column value will not throw any error.

So you need to **always mention column names in your INSERT query** wherever used

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), Status INT)
INSERT INTO @Table (id, name) VALUES (1,'Name')
```

`If you didn't specify the column names in INSERT query and add new column to the table will affect that query`. Please make sure whether you specified the column names.

Comment: Not an answer: question is about adding a column.

Comment: It does not answer the question. By definition an ANSWER should satisy the QUESTION!

Comment: 3 upvotes for something that is not actually an answer! SO is BROKEN.