# How to display entire table in SQL but limit the display length of 1 column

Tags: sql, substring

I've found that you can use `SUSBSTRING()` to limit display and limit one column.

But what if I want to display ALL columns and still limit just the length of one.

Comment: Use SUSBSTRING on the column you need

Comment: I highly doubt `SUSBSTRING` would work. :P

Answer (score 1):

You would do:

```
select col1, col2, col3, substring(col4, 10) as col4, col5, col6, . . .
from table t;
```

When doing a `select`, it is a good idea to list out the columns anyway.

Comment: So there's no way to use SELECT * FROM table;

And add substring to it?

Comment: You can do things like `SELECT SUBSTRING(col1, 10), *, SUBSTRING(col4, 5) FROM TABLE` if you want... But of course, those columns will appear twice: one time complete and one time just the first characters.

Comment: Don't use `*` in your query

Comment: also see here to understand why : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24544796/add-a-column-in-ms-sql-server-table/24545136#24545136